# Why is this the output of the pointer?

Tags: c, pointers

My textbook has a question that asks what will the output be of the following code snippet:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int arr[3] = {2, 3, 4};
    char *p;
    p = arr;
    p = (char*)((int*)(p));
    printf("%d, ", *p);
    p = (int*)(p+1);
    printf("%d", *p);
    return 0;
}
```

Options:

A.  2, 3

B.  2, 0

C.  2, Garbage value

D.  0, 0

According to the textbook the answer is `B`, but I'm confused - can someone explain *why*?

Comment: So, what is wrong? What did you expect? What did you try to answer this yourself? What does you favorite C book say? What **specifically** about that do you not understand? Did you try **anything** before asking?

Comment: With this type of question it can be very hard to pin down what exactly one does not understand and even harder to figure out which keywords to search for.

Learning the entirety of the C language would obviously still answer their question but seems kinda out of proportion.

What *should* they have tried in your opinion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Warning:* Some of this is rather simplified.

It's about memory layout. When you define `arr`, it is an array of `int` and looks like this in memory:

> 2, 3, 4

But each `int` is (or rather may be, C is kinda platform dependent.) four `char`s long. So when viewed as an array of `char` it looks like this:

> 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0

As `p` is of type `char *`, adding one to `p` advances your pointer by one as if in the second perspective. Therefore you get this output.

Comment: No, it's about invoking undefined behaviour.

Comment: 1) Didn't you just comment on the fact that you don't seem to be sure what the question exactly is about? 2) Please elaborate. Which undefined behaviour are you referencing?

Comment: 1) Why would that change the problem? Btw. I did did not comment about the question being unclear, but just being unclear what OP **specifically** asks for. You might want to review rules for questions. Apparnetly this another "I'm too lazy to go fishing, gimme teh fish" question. 2) Well, it is **your** answer, how about finding out yourself?

Comment: 1a) It doesn't change the problem, I am just honestly curious. 1b) To me it didn't look like that kind of question, but I acknowledge that you probably have more experience with this, meaning I will continue thinking about it. 2) I currently have to much else to do, but I'll probably look at it at a later point again.

Comment: @HermannDöppes: your answer suppose little-endianess, isn't it ?

Comment: @mpromonet Yes, one of the warned-about platformdependentations / simplifications.